# How to change letters to lowercase in a string recursively?

Tags: python, recursion

I've been given a lab using the `ord()` and `chr()` functions to convert letters to ASCII values and vice versa to check if the letter entered is upper or lower case. I got that part down, but the second part is to change uppercase letters in a string to lowercase recursively.

E.g. of how it's supposed to work:

```
>>> lowercase("Hello")
hello
```

It's kinda confusing, I don't know if I have to use the mapping function or what.

Here's what I have:

```
def lowercase(word): #accepts a string
    if word == []: #base case
        return []
    else:
        letter = ord(word[0])      #converts first character to ASCII Value
        if letter in range(65, 91):      #Checks if character is uppercase (ASCII uppercase Values)
            return chr(letter + 32) + lowercase(word[1:])      #converts letter to lower case by adding 32
        elif letter in range(97, 123):     #if letter is lowercase return the letter (ASCII lowercase Values)
            return chr(letter) + lowercase(word[1:])

WORD = str(raw_input("Enter a word: "))
print lowercase(WORD)
```

I have an idea of how it's supposed to work but that code is obviously not correct. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Avoid 'magic numbers' in your code. `if letter in range(65, 91)` should be `if 'A'<=letter<='Z'`, etc.

Comment: Check your base case.

Comment: @DYZ - The point is that OP has to use `ord` and `chr`, which means that `letter` is an integer representation of the character.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 Then OP should use `range(ord('A'), ord('Z')+1)`. By using 'magic numbers', they are looking for a trouble.

Comment: Sorry about the indentation....... to clarify, I get an index error at `letter = ord(word[0])`. @DYZ @lluvatar @TigerhawkT3 I changed my base case to `if len(word) == 0: return 0` Now I get a type error... cannot concatenate str and int objects. I thought lists can hold any value :/

Comment: @trayceetrace Your `word` is not a list; it is a string. You base case is wrong.

Comment: @DYZ Okay! I see it now. I have as my base case `if len(word) == 0: return word` and it seems to be working. Thanks a lot for opening my eyes man.

Comment: i read three times, and i still do not understand the code. the number is killing me.

Comment: @宏杰李 ahh it's fairly straightforward. Don't kill yourself over it. It works and that is what matters... well with the new base case highlighted in my last comment.

Comment: @宏杰李 May I ask what you don't understand about it? I don't quite understand what "Magic Numbers" are as another comment had said.

Comment: @DYZ, they are not magic, they are ASCII.

Comment: @wwii They are called "magic" http://wiki.c2.com/?MagicNumber

Comment: @wwii: they are "magic" in the sense that they *only* mean something in ASCII. Not only is using numbers where you can use *what you mean by them* less clear, it is a good habit to separate "local" conventions - e.g., "everybody is using ASCII and everybody knows what these numbers represents" - from what you want a program to do. Compare with using `x = ceil(Math.PI)` when you want to make `x = 4`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your base case is incorrect. You should check for an empty string and not an empty list.

```
if word == '': #base case
    return ''
```